# Apache POI gets java.io.IOException on tmp dir in multithread

Tags: java, multithreading, apache, apache-poi

I have a java application that gets a request to create an XLSX file.
this application is multi-threaded which means that 5 users simultaneously can run a report.
my issue is that when the report is huge and 5 users create reports together i get this message `java.io.IOException: Could not create temporary directory '`
this is probably caused because one of the 5 threads deleted the java.tmp.dir and the other 4 threads failed.

how do i resolve that?
one of my suggested solutions is to give each thread a different java.io.tmpdir, is that something that can be done?

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10224

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks but this addresses to issue with "Accessing the same document in multiple threads will not work"
the issue is not with the same document. every thread creates a different document but they all have the same java.io.tmpdir and one thread sometimes deletes it for the other threads

Comment: Sorry that this was not clear form the code which you had not provided.

Comment: i seriously doubt poi is deleting the tmp dir.  that is shared by the _entire_ jvm, so that would be a big no-no.  the poi library is very mature and i seriously doubt bad behavior like that would still exist in the library.  are you deleting any files/directories in your code?  what's the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @peroxide: Are you satisfied with the given answers? No? Well as a member for such a long time you should know why. Yo have not provided any code which shows your problem. You have provided an error but neither the whole error message nor the stacktrace. So how shall somebody be able giving any satisfying answer?

Comment: @jtahlborn i'm giving the application a different java.io.tmpdir and its not using the default one. thats why i know that it must be the POI thats deleting it.

Comment: @AxelRichter i've provided everything there is to know about the issue. the code in this case would have just confused people. the apache poi implementation is the same as in their documentation. but thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution will be while creating temp directory then thread should append some prefix to identify uniquely .So there will be no concurrent modification to same folder.

While implementation you have to consider how many request can simultaneously process.You can not create lot of directory.

One solution will be using thread pool and a queue to hold request if request is coming more than you can process.

or If there is similarity in content then you can create a template and change some data dynamically.So only clone will work

Answer (score 1):

I may first check if your methods, in relation to write those .xlsx files, are thread safe. 
And your theads may race to write the same files concurrently.

Comment: i've already checked that, its thread safe. the only issue is with the apache POI that sometimes deletes the tmp folder.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to forbide POI to delete the directory when empty (from https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57200#c4)

```
touch /tmp/poifiles/.dontdeleteonexitonnonuniquedirectories
```